# Do Mac OS apps have access to MAC address?

Tags: macos, mac-address

Do applications installed on Mac OS have access to the device's MAC address? I believe iOS disallowed apps from accessing the MAC address on iPhones with iOS 11, but I don't know if the same applied for Mac OS on MacBooks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in general macOS applications can get to the MAC address of the network interfaces in your computer.