# How to prevent apps from accessing real MAC address?

Tags: terminal, network, privacy, mac-address

I would like to [prevent apps in my M1 Mac from accessing my real MAC address](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/387234/do-mac-os-apps-have-access-to-mac-address) is there absolutely anything that I can do to hide real MAC address from apps in my computer. If I [spoof MAC address automatically at boot](https://github.com/sunknudsen/privacy-guides/blob/master/how-to-spoof-mac-address-and-hostname-automatically-at-boot-on-macos/README.md) will this be enough to trick the apps into thinking the spoofed MAC address is my real MAC address? Or can the apps still get get to the MAC address of the network interface in my computer? Absolutely any help is appreciated.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve here? You seem to be building to some end goal, but you're not telling us what it is. There may be another way to achieve this… or it may be a fruitless quest; either way, it could save a lot of wasted effort.

Comment: Since MAC addresses could be used to track us hiding it completely from prying eyes could enhance privacy.

Comment: MAC addresses nominally never pass borders, ie never leave the building. Some apps will have a MAC check - usually games etc to prevent double logins or banned players from returning - but this is passed directly by the app to the game servers; it doesn't 'leak'. Often, this is combined with an overall computer 'fingerprint' which is much harder to spoof. MAC addresses are also randomised when connectiong to unknown networks - https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/security/secb9cb3140c/web

Comment: Thank you so much for answering this question I was wondering though does spoofing MAC address on boot just like in that guide I linked above affect apple devices' inherent ability to randomize MAC address as given in the article you linked, I mean would the MAC address be still randomized or not?

Comment: I don't know. I've never cared enough to need to test it. For why… see above. I'd still like to know what you're **actually** trying to achieve. You still haven't told us. It makes it look very much like an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Comment: It's perfectly valid to want to reduce tracking by apps. MAC addresses don't leave the local network through normal internet transactions (though any router or AP can track it), but they can be exfiltrated by the apps themselves (or embedded 3rd-party code). iOS has largely solved this problem, but ifaik it's still a problem on macOS. Unfortunately we are at the mercy of OSes and their privacy tools to reduce trackability surface area. Browsers are better than apps by far in this regard. Spoofing may help. You may also want to look at VMs.

Comment: @Tetsujin Let me build on this question, as I am also curious if a hardware mac address can be spoofed/hidden. An app I am using requires a mac address to be run on a registered machine. This app is shared across 2 computers, but it will only work in one of them (mac address). When I spoof the mac address (in terminal, the device address is changed) the app still sees the hardware original mac address.  Also in system preferences, the mac address is not changed. Thoughts?

Comment: @jackkelly - I have no idea. I've always just used Little Snitch to stop apps phoning home.